# Scaling of Cloud Service (Classic) via Powershell or Terraform

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-cloud-services

It's not possible to deploy the Cloud Service (classic) via terraform, So I have used Arm Template and Deploy Cloud Service (Classic). Following is the code.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "classicCloudService" {
  name                = "testSyedClassic"
  resource_group_name = var.resourceGroup
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  template_content    = file("arm_template.json")
  tags                = local.resourceTags
}
```

Following is the ARM Template which I have used.

```
 {
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
          "dnsName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "testClassicSyed"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "westeurope"
          }
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('dnsName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",        
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames",
            "properties": {}
          }
        ],
        "outputs": {}
      }
```

As scaling options are missing in the ARM/TF Template. I want to scale like below, As this is only possible via Powershell. (As far as I know). But it's in old Azure Module.

CloudService

TaskWorkerRole: 1

WorkerRole1: 1

LongRunningTaskworkerRole: 1

DialogCloudService

TaskWorkerRole: 1

Webhook: 1

```
Set-AzureRole -ServiceName '<your_service_name>' -RoleName '<your_role_name>' -Slot <target_slot> -Count <desired_instances>
```

Can we use Set-AzRole or any other command to scale this? Or can we also do this via Terraform or Do we have any ARM Template for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use Set-AzRole or any other command to scale this? Or can we
> also do this via Terraform or Do we have any ARM Template for this?

[image]

No we can not use set-AzRole ,Because [**`The Azure Resource Manager and classic deployment models`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models) represent two different ways of deploying and managing your Azure solutions. To achieve that  we can use the below `PowerShell cmdlts` to scale out the roles.

```
Set-AzureRole -ServiceName '<your_service_name>' -RoleName '<your_role_name>' -Slot <target_slot> -Count <desired_instances>
```

For more information please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***How to scale an Azure Cloud Service (classic) in PowerShell***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale-powershell)

*Alternatively,* if you want to use Portal please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***How to configure auto scaling for a Cloud Service (classic) in the portal***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale-portal)